# PHP custom login Page with sessions and wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I could use some help. I am a beginner with programming php. I am using PHP because my website is done using wordpress. I have a custom login page developed using PHP.  I have an employee portal where the user logs in which is sessioned. Now, my issue is i have a wordpress shortcode for "Tabs" within the loggedin page. The tabs contain a bunch of absolute links for employees only. The issue now is when i click on those links and then i logout i am still able to access those links externally or bookmark it and never have to login again.  How can i either session the shortcode for "tabs" or then how can i session it such a way that when a user logs out those links automatically would redirect the user to the login page.  Basically if you have bookmarked or copy paste the link to the browser you should be redirected to the login page.  How can i achieve this?

The shortcode is like so: do_shortcode('[ctv_ultimate_oxi  id="521"]'); - This are tabs on the loggedin page.  The only issue is the absolute links that open on new page. Those links are accessible when bookmarked or copied and pasted later after the user logs out.

I will really appreciate some help with a sample code. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: before to display a protected page, you can test is the user is connected with the function `is_user_logged_in` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: On the login page where the user puts in the login credential i have session which i am check on the loggedin page and i am getting the user name and welcome message. Again the issue is with the absolute links which open on a new page and user logs out then that page which the user opened is still accessible.  I want that absolute link page to redirect the user to the login page once the user has logged out or session has expired. 
How can i achieve this. Please help.